# WPF Multiple datagrid causing memory issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, memory-leaks

My WPF project has a tabcontrol which hosts multiple datagrid control. Each of the datagrid contains about 1000 rows and users are expected to have more than 10 datagrids open in the same time (with each of them being hosted in different tabpages).

The thing is my application would crash at the 5 - 6th datagrid due to out of memory exception. After hours of research I found out that the only viable way to resolve this issue is to enable UI virtualization. However this is not an option because I need smooth scrolling for my datagrid and enabling UI virtualization would disable smooth scrolling.

Another solution would be to change the scrollunit to pixel instead of item based. This is however also not an option in my case because I am restricted to run the application in .NET Framework 4.0 (the feature is only available in 4.5).

Also I am quite certain that it was the rows that was causing the memory issue because if I run the application without a datagrid I could easily load up to 100s viewmodels.

What I am thinking is would it be possible for me to temporarily dispose controls created in the non-visible tabpages and create them only whenever user navigates to the respective tabpage? Else is there any other way to get around this?

Comment: IIRC virtualisation should not prevent smooth scrolling, in fact it should improve scrolling because the same UI elements are recycled, which lightens the workload considerably.

Comment: I think the best way to implement is load and un-load your grid on the Tab Active/Deactive . Why you are loading all the grids in one shot.

Comment: Since you've already disqualified virtualization, there's quite nothing that can be done except changing the way the ui works. If this really causes an out of memory exception (as opposed to handle leakage), start analyzing what uses most memory - UI or data objects.  Do the data objects have references to further objects that could be turned lazy? And one more thing - you speak of ViewModels...Is that one per data row or one per data context?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it is the UI that is causing the memory issue.  It is one datacontext/VM per datagrid and there is not many nested childs for the VM so I doubt the data objects is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Not using datagrids would help.

While such controls can be convenient to use fact is that they are far from lightweight.

Screen will hold ~30 rows at once so there is no need to pollute memory with thousand of them, having loaded more rows to some dataset can smooth up scrolling as you will be feeding grid with pre-fetched data,

You can even create offline cache in temporary file if data is not changing constantly.